# What does the word "as"'mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from this [video](https://youtu.be/0bNdhM4vt4I). It is at 7 minute and 13 second. Here is the context:

> So, you should add as much high quality salt **as** tastes good on your next meal.

Does the speaker mean that one should add as much salt as they wants provided that if tastes good, or one should add it because it tastes good? Anyway, why did he omitted the pronoun *it*?

Comment: Out of curiosity, where do you think the word *it* should go?

Comment: I think part of your confusion is the verb **tastes** itself.   Compare: *You should tip the taxi driver as much as **seems appropriate** on your next ride*.  In the original, *you* are the taster; in that taxi example, *you* are the judge who determines what is appropriate: as much as seems appropriate *to you* and as much as tastes good *to you*.

Comment: *It seems a good bargain **(to me)***.  *It tastes rancid **(to me)***.

Comment: stangdon: Right after the word "as"

Comment: So would it be more gramatical to say one should add as much high quality salt as it tastes good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has neither meaning. That "as ... as" locution means "add the exact amount of salt that tastes good to you." The second "as" acts as a "that."